# hyperlink on combo box flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

need to have a hyperlink on the combo box value. On click of the hyperlink should navigate to required page? Is it possible?

NOTE:
No need to have hyperlink for all the values. If user select a value in the combo box then need to display the selected value with a hyperlink and if required user can click on the hyperlink to navigate to the required page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While it is technologically possible, I am not sure if it is a good approach from UX perspective.  It is better to display the hyperlink outside of the combobox, and only shows the link when the relevant option is selected in the comobox.

Comment: Hello Tianzhen, we also taught about this from UX prespective. Any hint how it can be implemented with hyperlink inside combo box. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

override the click handler of the checkbox ..
on handling dispatch a custom event to pass in a link ...